# How to use segue to pass taken photo

Tags: ios, photo

I want to pass a photo taken in the first view controller to a second view controller. I want the user to take the photo in the first view controller and then crop in in the second view controller and then save.. So its like..  User take photo→crop→save.  I just want to do this simple task but taking me days to get the segue go right.. Is segue the best way to do this? or is there a more easier way to do this task.  I am a beginner in objective -c so its making me confused with segues and all the stuff.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement `prepareForSegue:sender:` in the source view controller. This will give you access to the `destinationViewController` via the passed `storyboard`. Then you can set the image so its available when the destination view controller is displayed.

Answer (score 0):

As far as segue is concerned you need to create a segue arrow using storyboard by dragging arrow from first view controller to second view controller, and most importantly you need to give the segue an identifier or name.

For firing you segue you may do it programatically, like:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowSecondScreen" sender:self];
```

For handling things when segue is fired you need to write prepareForSegue() method, you may pass any object from current viewController to next viewController:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowSecondScreen"])
    {
        SecondViewController *secondViewController = segue.destinationViewController;
    secondViewController.imageObj = image;
    }
}
```