# Xcode UICollectionView - select item and send to multiple UIViewControllers

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a `UICollectionView` containing buttons that link to other view controllers. What is the best way to show different controllers when buttons are tapped?

It seems I can create an array containing the various view controller ids and use the `performSegueWithIdentifier` method. I am stuck on referencing the array items in this method.

If my array is named `MY_ARRAY`, can I reference its indexes in this method? Or does it always require a string?

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:MY_ARRAY sender:self];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use segue to pass taken photo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17740424/how-to-use-segue-to-pass-taken-photo)

Answer (score 1):

You can tag your `UIButtons` and use their tags as indexes in the array with segue IDs.

Your `MY_ARRAY` would contain segue IDs. Example:

```
MY_ARRAY = @[@"SegueID1", @"SegueID2", @"SegueID3"]
```

Then in the `IBAction` of your button

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender
{
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender;

    NSUInteger index = button.tag;

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:MY_ARRAY[index] sender:self];
}
```